# Creating a PDF using iText without saving it to a temp file

Tags: java, itext

code:

```
private String FILE = "e:/FirstPdf.pdf";

public void preparePDF() {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfFile);
            document.open();
            addTitlePage(document);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

everything works fine but what i want is to not save the pdf into a temporary folder but rather just insert it to a `private File` or something. I'm creating a web application that has a function to download PDF files, i just need the pdf to be inside a variable.

Comment: PDF cannot be store inside a variable, save it to specific location store it's full path into a variable and pass that path to download file function to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PdfWriter` has a static method `getInstance(Document document, OutputStream os)`. Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to store the contents to a byte array. Later on, use this array to send the file to the user. Perhaps you need to wrap the array into a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

This way, you do not need to store the file on the file system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ByteArrayOutputStream`, if you dont want to save the `PDF`. take a look at this  [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the `document` to an `OutputStream` instead of a file. If you want to be able to generate and download the PDF file dynamically (i.e. if it doesn;t take more than a second or so to generate), then you could create a servlet and write to `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`.

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ByteArrayOutputStream to convert any image to pdf with out saving into a temp file.

```
public static byte[] imageToPDFConverterByteArray(byte[] sourcFileURL) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(sourcFileURL);
        Image image = new Image(data);
        document.add(image);
        document.close();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return sourcFileURL;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).